# Converting non-Ascii characters to int in C, the extra bits are supplemented by 1 rather than 0

Tags: c, string, utf-8, type-conversion, non-ascii-characters

When coding in C, I have accidently found that as for non-Ascii characters, after they are converted from `char` (1 byte) to `int` (4 bytes), the extra bits (3 bytes) are supplemented by 1 rather than 0. (As for Ascii characters, the extra bits are supplemented by 0.) For example:

```
char c[] = "ā";
int i = c[0];
printf("%x\n", i);
```

And the result is `ffffffc4`, rather than `c4` itself. (The UTF-8 code for ā is `\xc4\x81`.)

Another related issue is that when performing right shift operations `>>` on a non-Ascii character, the extra bits on the left end are also supplemented by 1 rather than 0, even though the char variable is explicitly converted to unsigned int (for as for signed int, the extra bits are supplemented by 1 in my OS). For example:

```
char c[] = "ā";
unsigned int u_c;
int i = c[0];
unsigned int u_i = c[0];

c[0] = (unsigned int)c[0] >> 1; 
u_c = (unsigned int)c[0] >> 1;      
i = i >> 1;
u_i = u_i >> 1;
printf("c=%x\n", (unsigned int)c[0]); // result: ffffffe2. The same with the signed int i.
printf("u_c=%x\n", u_c); // result: 7fffffe2.
printf("i=%x\n", i); // result: ffffffe2.
printf("u_i=%x\n", u_i); // result: 7fffffe2.
```

Now I am confused with these results... Are they concerned with the data structures of char, int and unsigned int, or related to my operating system (ubuntu 14.04), or related to the ANSI C requirements? I have tried to compile this program with both gcc(4.8.4) and clang(3.4), but there is no difference.

Thank you so much!

Comment: No, it's just sign extension, and the fact that on your architecture, `char` is a signed type. If you have `char c;`, use `i = (unsigned char)c;` to cast `c` to an unsigned char type first, so that the character code will always be nonnegative.

Comment: you can choose by using command line options for example gcc `-funsigned-char`. But if someone needs to have 8 bit signed or unsigned value it better to use fixed size types instead of 'char' : `uint8_t` or `int8_t`

Comment: Ah, yes! After I use `unsigned char` and `uint8_t`, everything comes back to normal. Thanks! @NominalAnimal @PeterJ

Comment: if `uint8_t` *exists* it matches `unsigned char`

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Now I understand. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is *implementation-defined* whether `char` is signed or unsigned. On x86 computers, `char` is customarily a *signed integer type*; and on ARM it is customarily an *unsigned integer type*.

A signed integer will be *sign-extended* when converted to a larger signed type;

a signed integer converted to *unsigned integer* will use the modulo arithmetic to wrap the *signed* value into the range of the unsigned type as if by repeatedly adding or subtracting the maximum value of the unsigned type + 1.

---

The solution is to use/cast to `unsigned char` if you want the value to be *portably* zero-extended, or for storing small integers in range `0..255`.

Likewise, if you want to store signed integers in range `-127..127/128`, use `signed char`.

Use `char` if the signedness doesn't matter - the implementation will probably have chosen the type that is the most efficient for the platform.

---

Likewise, for the assignment

```
unsigned int u_c; u_c = (uint8_t)c[0];,
```

Since `-0x3c` or `-60` is not in the range of `uint16_t`, then the actual value is the value *(mod UINT16_MAX + 1)* that falls in the range of `uint16_t`; iow, we add or subtract `UINT16_MAX + 1` (*notice that the integer promotions could trick here so you might need casts if in C code*) until the value is in the range. `UINT16_MAX` is naturally always `0xFFFFF`; add 1 to it to get `0x10000`. `0x10000 - 0x3C` is `0xFFC4` that you saw. And then the `uint16_t` value is zero-extended to the `uint32_t` value.

Had you run this on a platform where `char` is `unsigned`, the result would have been `0xC4`!

---

BTW in `i = i >> 1;`, `i` is a signed integer with a *negative value*; C11 says that the value is [*implementation-defined*](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.7p5), so the actual behaviour can change from compiler to compiler. The [GCC manuals state](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integers-implementation.html) that

> Signed `>>` acts on negative numbers by *sign extension*.

However a strictly-conforming program should not rely on this.

Comment: And, clearly, the 1-bits being questioned indicate that negative numbers are, unsurprisingly, in a two's complement format.

Comment: @TomBlodget GCC supports only 2's complement, so to have otherwise would have been a big surprise indeed :D

Comment: @Antti Haapala have you seen any computer system developed in the last 30-40 years which uses 1complement? The only one I have heard about is format of the index bitfield in the Intel AVX extension prefix - but it is not very likely to program it "manually".

Comment: @PeterJ Well, I have not seen, I have not touched one's complement - ever personally. It seems that new UNIVAC systems have been built even within last 20 years to aid in migration to modern systems...

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Thank you so much for your answer! So this issue is not related to non-Ascii/Ascii, but related to whether the char variable has a negative or a positive value. That it seems to be concerned with Ascii is just because the codes of all ascii characters are in [0, 127], and thus they all have a positive value in a signed char, isn't it?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Now I use `unsigned char`, and it is zero-extended. :) But I have one more question. If I use `unsigned int u_c; u_c = (uint8_t)c[0];`, it is also zero-extended. Is it because when converting `signed char` to `uint8_t`, as both are of the same size (1 byte), there is no bit extended; and then when converting `uint8_t` to `unsigned int`, as both are unsigned integers, the extra bits are complemented by 0? (And the result of `unsigned int u_c; u_c = (uint16_t)c[0];` is `ffc4`. It is because in this process, only 1 byte is extended from `signed char` to `unsigned int`, isn't it?)

Comment: @none I've addressed this too in my answer.